# Compare macros in C from function return value

Tags: c, unix

```
if (ISADIGIT != atoi2(&word[i])){
```

Why can't I do that (see above). I get "expected expression" ?

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define STARTSWITH0 "Starts with 0";
#define NEGATIVESIGNNOTATBEGINNING "Negative sign not at beginning";

#define ISADIGIT "Is a digit";

#define MORETHANONENEGATIVESIGN "More than one negative sing";
#define MORETHANONEDECIMALPLACE "More than one decimal place";
#define NUMBERTOOLARGEORNUMBERTOOSMALL "Number too large or number too small";
#define CONVERSIONERROR "Conversion Error";
#define CANNOTCONTAINLETTERS "Cannot contain letters";

char* atoi2(char str[]);
int main(int argc, char ** argv){

    char c, word[1000]; int count;


        printf("enter word: ");
        count = 0;

        while(1){
            c = getchar();
            if (c == EOF); 
                return 0;

            if (c == ' ') {
                continue;
            }

            if (c == '\n' || c == '\t'){
                word[count] = '\0';
                break;
            }
            word[count++] = c;
        }
        int i;


    for (i = 0; i < count; i++){

        if (ISADIGIT != atoi2(&word[i])){
            printf("%s\n", atoi2(&word[i]));
            return 1;
        }

    }

    int sum;
    for (i = 0; i < count; i++){
        sum += word[i];
    }

    printf("sum is: %d", sum);


}


char* atoi2(char * str)
{
    int i, v, d, n, errno;
    i = v = d = n = 0;

    while(str[i] != '\0'){

        /* this means the first value is a 0, therefore it should not be numeric */
        if (i == 0 && str[i] == '0' && str[i+1] != '.' && str[i+1] != '\0') return STARTSWITH0;

        if(!isdigit(str[i])) {

            if (isalpha(str[i])) return CANNOTCONTAINLETTERS; /* must make sure the digit we receive is not a letter */

            if (str[i] == '-'  && i > 0) return NEGATIVESIGNNOTATBEGINNING; /* negative sign must come first */

            if (str[i] == '-'){ ++n; ++i; continue; } /* first negative sign, pass through */

            if (str[i] == '.') { ++d; } /* periods are ok, just not too many */

        }
        ++i;
    }

    if (n > 1) return MORETHANONENEGATIVESIGN; /* can't have more than one negative sign */

    if (d > 1) return MORETHANONEDECIMALPLACE; /* this means there is more than one decimal place */

    return ISADIGIT;
}
```

Thank you for all of your wonderful input. Here is the modified program

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define STARTSWITH0 1 /*"Starts with 0"*/
#define NEGATIVESIGNNOTATBEGINNING 2 /*"Negative sign not at beginning"*/
#define MORETHANONENEGATIVESIGN 3 /*"More than one negative sing"*/
#define MORETHANONEDECIMALPLACE 4 /*"More than one decimal place"*/
#define NUMBERTOOLARGE 5
#define CANNOTCONTAINLETTERS 6 /*"Cannot contain letters"*/
#define CONTAINSAPERIOD 7 /*"Integers cannot contain decimal points"*/

int atoi2(char *);
char * geterrorstring(int);
int main(int argc, char ** argv){

    char c, nums[1000][1000];

    while(1) {
        printf("enter numbers: ");
        int digits = 0, row = 0, maxrows = 1;

        /* gets data from user, puts it into an array */
        while(1){
            c = getchar();
            if (c == EOF) return 0;
            if (c == ' ' || c == '\t') { nums[row][digits] = '\0'; row++; maxrows++; digits = 0; }
            if (c == '\n'){ nums[row][digits] = '\0'; maxrows++; digits = 0; break; }
            nums[row][digits++] = c;
        }

        int i, j;

        int error = 0;

        /* sums up data from array and prints error message if digit is invalid */
        int sum = 0, msg = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < maxrows; i++){
                msg = atoi2(nums[i]);
                if (msg > 0){
                    printf("%s\n", geterrorstring(msg));
                    error = 1;
                }
            sum += atoi(nums[i]);
        }

        if (error == 1) continue;

        printf("sum is: %d\n", sum);

    }

}

char * geterrorstring(int code)
{
    switch (code) {
        case STARTSWITH0:
            return "Starts with 0";
            break;

        case NEGATIVESIGNNOTATBEGINNING:
            return "Negative signs must be at the begging of the number";
            break;

        case MORETHANONENEGATIVESIGN:
            return "You cannot have more than one negative sign in a number";
            break;

        case MORETHANONEDECIMALPLACE:
            return "More than one decimal place";
            break;

        case NUMBERTOOLARGE:
            return "Number too large";
            break;

        case CANNOTCONTAINLETTERS:
            return "Cannot contain letters";
            break;

        case CONTAINSAPERIOD:
            return "Integers do not have decimal places";

        default:
            return "I have no idea what error you have, but you got one";
            break;
    }
}


int atoi2(char * str)
{
    int i, v, n, errno;
    i = v = n = 0;

    while(str[i] != '\0'){

        /* this means the first value is a 0, therefore it should not be numeric */
        if (i == 0 && str[i] == '0' && str[i+1] != '.' && str[i+1] != '\0') return STARTSWITH0;

        if(!isdigit(str[i])) {

            if (isalpha(str[i])) return CANNOTCONTAINLETTERS; /* must make sure the digit we receive is not a letter */

            if (sizeof(atoi(str)) > sizeof(int)) return NUMBERTOOLARGE; /* make sure number is not that large */

            if (str[i] == '-'  && i > 0) { if (n > 1) { return MORETHANONENEGATIVESIGN; } return NEGATIVESIGNNOTATBEGINNING; } /* negative sign must come first */

            if (str[i] == '-'){ ++n; ++i; continue; } /* first negative sign, pass through */

            if (str[i] == '.') { return CONTAINSAPERIOD; } /* periods are ok, just not too many */

        }
        ++i;
    }

    if (n > 1) return MORETHANONENEGATIVESIGN; /* can't have more than one negative sign */

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `ISADIGIT` is a char array and you would need `strcmp` or `strncmp` if I am not mistaken.

Comment: @abhinole: All the strings are static, though, so comparing the pointers is not a terrible idea.

Comment: The thing about macros is that they are handled _before_ the actual compiler, and that the macro is replaced _verbatim_. This means that the semicolon you have will be there when the macro is replaced as well. Preprocessor statements are terminated by the end of the line, they don't need semicolons or other special characters to terminate them.

Comment: Didn't know this was a dumb question. I guess I will delete it.

Comment: @KerrekSB....Would you explain more? I am still unable to understand your comment.

Comment: I have been downvoted twice, I'm new to C and thought I had a valid question. I don't know how to explain the downvotes

Comment: @abhinole: String literals have static storage. You can compare pointers to their first elements for equality. That said, it's unspecified whether identical strings are pooled or not.

Comment: You would go a long way towards improving this program if you simply used integers for return codes instead of strings.  String return values are very hard to work with.

Comment: But they make it easy to print out what I want to the user.

Comment: @Dave- A commonly-used technique is to create a table that maps return values to strings (or a function that uses a `switch` block to do the same thing).  Strings are not first-class objects in C like they are in C++, which makes them especially difficult to work with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root cause of your immediate issue is the semicolon at the end of your macro definition (as piokuc pointed out).  Pre-processor statements do not need semicolons.  Here is another important thing else to consider with your current implementation:

Since `ISADIGIT` is a macro, the pre-processor will replace every instance of `ISADIGIT` in your code with the specified string.  You use `ISADIGIT` in multiple places, and each will be replaced by the string.  Each of these will be treated as a separate, independent string literal.  Their content happens to be the same, but they are separate objects.  This means that your `atoi2` function will return a pointer to the string literal contained inside the function, and your `main` function is comparing that pointer to a pointer to the string literal contained inside `main`.  Since these are pointers to different objects, they will always compare unequal.  The fact that they're strings that happen to contain the same contents is immaterial as far as the compiler is concerned.

That being said, this code may *appear* to work in some cases.  Some compilers have an optional optimization that saves space by combining identical string literals.  In that case, the expansion of the `ISADIGIT` macro would boil down to a pointer to a common string literal, and the comparison that you are doing in `main` could work.  However, you should never rely on a specific compiler optimization to be available and enabled for your code to work properly.  If you do that, you will run a strong risk of your code breaking if you upgrade your compiler, build with a different compiler, build a 'debug' version instead of a 'release' version, etc etc.

In general, don't use strings as return codes from a function.  Strings are not true objects in C (unlike other languages), and there are a lot of hidden "gotchas" involved in working with them.  The traditional way to return status codes from a function is to use an integer for a return value.  A function returns zero when it completes successfully, and a non-zero return value indicates an error of some sort.  Since you have all of your error codes abstracted as macros, you can simply replace the strings in the `#define` statements with numbers and change the return type of `atoi2` to `int`.  The only other change you would need to make is in the line where you `printf("%s")` the return value of `atoi2`.  You will need to have a separate method for turning an integer into a string.  The two common ways to do this are to use a function or a table:

```
// Function method:
// Use like: printf("%s", code_to_string(code));
const char* code_to_string(int code) {
    switch(code) {
        case STARTSWITH0:
            return "Starts with 0";
        case NEGATIVESIGNNOTATBEGINNING:
            return "Negative sign not at beginning";
        ...
        default:
            return "Unknown error";
    }
}

// Table method (assumes error codes are numbered 1,2,3,...
// Use like: printf("%s", error_strings[code]);
const char* error_strings[] = {
    "No error", // 0
    "Starts with 0", // 1
    "Negative sign not at beginning", // 2
    ...
};
```

Comment: Thank you for this awesome response. I have incorporated the changes you've recommended. See above.

Comment: @Dave- Your `geterrorstring` function needs to return something for the 'default' case.  Right now you'll fall off the end of the function, the return value will be undefined, and the code that calls this function could go haywire.

Comment: I added a return in the default case. Thanks bta

Answer (score 3):

Change

```
#define ISADIGIT "Is a digit";
```

to

```
#define ISADIGIT "Is a digit"
```

In your case it's OK to compare pointers to your string constants, contrary to what others say.

Comment: When debugging problems involving macros, it is sometimes useful to have your compiler run the pre-processor, output the result, and then halt.  You will be able to see what the code looks like after macro expansion, and errors like this can be easier to spot.

Comment: Actually, it's unspecified whether equal strings are pooled or not, so the value of `"a" == "a"` is implementation-defined.

Comment: I don't have a copy of the standard, so I cannot check it, but I guess you're right. However, all the C compilers I know do pool equal strings, especially if they are all in one compilation unit.